# why Thousands of sessions are creating in one hour

Tags: session, customer-session

we want to know how many session files are creating in session folder.

we are running this command from root directory of magento

ls -l | wc -l

when we run this command, we can see

thousands of sessions files are creating.

this is live site with less number of users visiting the site.

we also have mobile app for our site.

we want to know why this much sessions are creating.

almost 40,000 sessions are created until now lastin one hour.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced same issue in previous year. You might get some help I am posting here.
To handle session properly, take a look at http://ar.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php.

There you'll find these variables:

- session.gc_probability
- session.gc_divisor
- session.gc_maxlifetime

These control the garbage collector (GC) probability of running with each page request.

You could set those with [ini_set()](http://ar.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) at the beginning of your script or .htaccess file so you get certainty to some extent they will get deleted sometime.

Reference : [from here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654310/cleanup-php-session-files)
Also [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340249/windows-temp-directory-is-full-of-php-sessions-files-that-block-the-server)

Comment: it was coming from one I.p. we blocked it. now it reduced. but what you gave is really a great information, we will check it.....